# Duplicate Logger in python

Tags: python, logging

I have two scripts

- first.py
- second.py

in first.py, I am creating a logger as

```
log = logging.getLogger()
```

in second.py I am doing same thing as

```
log = logging.getLogger()
```

they are working fine individually. Problem is when I call first.py into second.py. Which lead to create two instance of logger. How to avoid this thing?

I want to use multiple such file to call in each other.

Comment: According to the docs: `Multiple calls to getLogger() with the same name will always return a reference to the same Logger object.` So how do you know that multiple loggers are being created?

Comment: in logging i can see one it for first.py and second one is for root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jai, it is not a problem to have multiple loggers, but they need different names.
Ideally, you set them up with `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. name is an name unique to each module which also corresponds to your package structure. You can use your own names, but most of the time that is more trouble than benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a name to the logger so that python could tell it's the same logger. 
In both first.py and second.py:

```
log = logging.getLogger('myLogger')
```